# match a whole row of a database table

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a table containing column Job_role , Exp_year and Job_id. Now I want to match a whole row containing one Job_role , Exp_year and Job_id. The Job_role , Exp_year and Job_id will be provided by the user. Now i want two query , one to match and another to insert the values if they are not found.
 I am using MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1)SELECT  Job_id, Job_role, Exp_year FROM UserTable 
   WHERE (Job_id, Job_role,Exp_year) NOT IN 
      (SELECT Job_id, Job_role, Exp_year FROM YourTable);
```

You can use this to view which entries aren't available in your database.

```
2)Insert into TableName (SELECT  Job_id, Job_role, Exp_year FROM UserTable 
       WHERE (Job_id, Job_role,Exp_year) NOT IN 
          (SELECT Job_id, Job_role, Exp_year FROM YourTable));
```

You can use this to insert the non-existing data. Let me know the results.